# What is the relationship in general between the number of threads and RAM usage?

Tags: multithreading, memory

What is the relationship in general between the number of threads and RAM usage?

Let's say the number of available threads is K, assuming K = "CPU(s) shown by lscpu command", and we have a some program which has some sort of parallelism.
As the number of threads used, (say *t* threads are used) increases, what is the general behavior of the memory consumption in the program? Is it O(t)?

Answer (score 0):

A thread comes with a certain amount of overhead. You need memory to thread state, thread local data,...

So obviously, if one thread requires X bytes of memory for that aforementioned information, then n threads will require n * X bytes.

So you a lower boundary there. But: what goes on top of that, depends on the workload each thread is processing. A thread might just be reading a file line by line, processing that and writing out one line at a time. Then it won't need much memory. But another thread might read a large image to memory, to then do all kinds of computations on that data. Thus asking for a general upper bound is simply meaningless.

Comment: I see. There is no surprise when the memory consumption goes up and down and then up again as the number of thread increases for a certain program, right?

Comment: Typically, threads do some sort of work. You would expect that more work results in more memory consumption.